# How can I simulate value from a parametric copula using no parametric margins

Tags: sampling, simulation, random-generation, copula

I know that if you fit your variables with parametric margins (e.g. beta, gamma) we can easily simulate from copula using the function Mvcd and rMvcd in R.but if you want to work with no parametric margins how can I simulate. I will be thankful for any information or code in R.
Edit:
as I know if you want to simulate with copulas you need to follow these steps:$\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$
1-Generate i.i.d. uniformly distributed random variables $U=\{u_i,i=1,...,N\}$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\$
2-set $y_1=u_1$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\$

3-set $u_2=C(y_2,|y_1)=C(y_2|u_1)=\frac{\partial C(y_2,u_1)}{\partial u_1}$
then $y_2=h^{-1}(u_2,y_1,\theta)$ in which the h function
is defined as the conditional copula.

4-Continue until we obtain $y_N=h^{-1}(u_N,y_{N-1},\theta)$.

My question is when we do all these steps It should be noted that ${y1; y2; . . . ; yn}simulated from steps 1 to 4 are the time series in the frequency domain (i.e., marginals), and we will need to perform the one-to-one transformation to obtain the corresponding time series simulated in the real domain (e.g.,
through parametric distribution, empirical distribution, or kernel density based on the observed time series).

I fitted an empirical distribution to a set of time series data (Y) by following code in R:
Ye=rank(Y)/(length(Y)+1)

So I need the inverse of this ecdf for transform the simulated data the original domain

Comment: The copula itself has standard uniform margins.

Comment: Thank you, Glen, for your answer but can you explain more please. Because what I mean that if I didn't want to restrictive my choose of margins (by choose them by the parametric way) how can I simulate using the empirical margins  and got good result

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to clarify that you want to work with empirical margins. I don't think anyone would be likely to guess that from the present question. I am pretty sure that there are some questions that relate to this (though maybe not any with really satisfying answers).

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thank you for your kind answer. I was edited my question I will be thankful if you have any information to help me

Comment: Why not just hit your marginals with the empirical probability integral transform, ecdf(marginal)(marginal)? Then you get rid of the effects of the marginals altogether, whether you fit them with parametric distributions or not.

Comment: @Dave Thank you, Dave, for your answer but I really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What part don’t you follow?

Comment: @Dave if we want to use the empirical probability integral transform you need to know the marginal it has to be specif ite from a parametric family in my case I was use the semi-parametric approach to fit the copula and when I want to simulate from this fitted copula by the function rcopula I got result in the marginal domain [0,1] so I need to know the inverse of the empirical CDF that I used to fit the data in the first place to get back to my original data

Comment: @Dave can you please check this link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137068/how-do-i-convert-simulated-values-from-a-copula-to-real-observations-r it the same as my problem but in his case his use parametric quantile to get back to the original domain but I want to that with non-parametric marginal that's my problem

Comment: The point of the empirical probability integral transform is that you treat the empirical data as the population. You do not need to know the parametric form of the population from which the data were selected.

Comment: @Dave to be clear when we finished the step 4 the original domain is $x_1=F^{-1}(y_1)$

Comment: The empirical probability integral transform is transform the any variable to the uniform domain but I have the variable $y_i$ is in the  uniform domain I want to transform it to original domain by the inverse of the  empirical probability integral transform is transform .my question is how can do that in r

Answer (score 1):

Now I see what you want to do. When you get simulated values from your copula, each marginal of course$^{\dagger}$ has values on $[0,1]$. These correspond to the quantiles of your original distribution.

The `quantile` function in R undoes the empirical probability integral transform.

So you'll simulate some `x` and `y` marginals that are of course$^{\dagger}$ on $[0,1]$. Then you'll hit `x` and `y` with `quantile`. Something like...

```
# define original x and y marginals: 
#
x_orig <- whatever it is
y_orig <- whatever it is

# Empirical probability integral transform
#
ex <- ecdf(x_orig)(x_orig)
ey <- ecdf(y_orig)(y_orig)

# Estimate your copula using ex and ey as the marginals
# Then sample from your copula: get x and y marginals

# Transform x and y back to the domains of x_orig and y_orig
#
x_simulated <- quantile(x_orig, x)
y_simulated <- quantile(y_orig, y)
```

$^{\dagger}$Why "of course"?

Comment: Since Cross Validated isn't for questions about coding, I'd like to use the comments to clarify any confusing points in my post so that I can go back and edit the post. Let's start with you answering my question at the end, however :)

Comment: Thank you so much that's really what I want, but what am not understood that the quantile function "quantile(x, prob=sec()..) " why you use x and y like probability in your code what is normal for me is to right "quantile(x,x_orig)"?!

Comment: @NAAMA That’s just the way the function works in R. Other software my work the other way, though R’s order makes sense to me. If you run quantile on some data without specifying any quantiles in the second argument, it gives you the typical quantiles of interest: 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dave I will try to implement this code to my data and figure out the result.can I ask you again if am I confusing about something after implementation Dave?!

Comment: @NAAMA Depending on the question, it may be better for you to post a new question, but please do post implementation questions on Stack Overflow. This question is arguably borderline but perhaps should be on SO.

Comment: Thank you, last question when I implemented you code I got some percentage value with the simulated value what does mean.what is the meaning of this percentage number

Comment: That’s the percentile you which you’re quantiles correspond, though you’re free to ignore those numbers. I don’t think they will be particularly helpful to you. I think there’s a way to get rid of that pairing and just get the vector of simulated observations, though I don’t know offhand how to do that. That would be a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: okay thanks a lot for helpful information and your time.